# "Hello, name!";

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

Your challenge is to make a simple program that takes the [input] and formats it as "Hello, [input]!"

### Input

Either a function call variable or STDIN, this is the name. Can contain any character, UTF-8, and can be empty - would result in `Hello,!`. Also newlines in the input are fine -

```
On a new
line 
->
Hello, On a new
line!
```

**Why? Because the challenge is not about if the message makes sense or not, it's about 'how quickly can you *format*?'.**

### Output

Hello, !

## Example

Here would be a program in CJam:

```
"Hello, %s!"qae%

lolad -> Hello, lolad!

John Smith -> Hello, John Smith!

this is a
new line -> 
Hello, this is a
new line!

<null> -> Hello, !
```

## Winner

The winner is the answer with the shortest bytes, as always.

Comment: This appears to mainly be outputting the input, with some extra text added, which is already a challenge. Therefore I have voted to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Despite their similarities this challenge differs in a non-trivial way from Simple cat program: Simple cat program restricts submissions to full programs while this challenge does not.

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 13 bytes

```
'!>`^
Hello,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X13RLiGOyyM1JydfR@H//5TEouy81OJiHYXcSoX8nBSFtKLM1LwUAA)

#### Explanation

```
^
Hello,
```

This part prepends the `Hello,` (and a space) to the input. Then `>` lets us configure the implicit output of the program and with `'!` we can append the exclamation mark to the output (basically a generalisation of printing with a trailing linefeed).

Answer (score 2):

## [pl](https://github.com/quartata/pl-lang), 9 bytes

```
Hello, _!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8j5/98jNScnX0chXvH/f5fUvLzMYgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 18 bytes

```java
s->"Hello, "+s+"!"
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY3NCsIwEITvfYoxpxa1LyB6FkEvPaqHNY02mm6kWRWRPnuNkqsIs7A/3@yc6U7Tc30ZtKMQsCbLrwywLKY7kjbYfEagks7yCTpPTShmcd/HigpCYjU2YMwxhOlCLY1zfgI1DmM1UsMsi9T1dnCRSvDd2xptjEsft3tQkbKeQUxb@puU13gSxzmXOlfOO6pV8U3@Ta18w6haK81fVBobEEU7ZvOAs2z@ehLQZ/3wBg)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
”Ÿ™, ÿ!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPcozsetSzSUTi8X/H///LEEgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 19 bytes

```perl
say"Hello, ",<>,"!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJIzUnJ19HQUnHxk5HSVHp//@c/JzElH/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDfQMAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```
fn a->"Hello, #{a}!"end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@u/pr1dQWlKsofE/LU8hUddOySM1JydfR0G5OrFWUSk1L@W/pp4GUFFRamKKglViTo6m5v@k/KS0cq7E8tS08lQA)

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```
IO.puts"Hello, #{IO.read :all}!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v/f01@voLSkWMkjNScnX0dBuRooUJSamKJglZiTU6uo9P9/IhdXEgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 21 bytes

```
x:"Hello, "
+?
+"!"
O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/7/CSskjNScnX0dBiUvbnktbSVGJy/////8lGZnFChmJxVx5qeU5mXmpxVyZeQqZJQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 12 bytes

Couldn't think of a simpler solution.

```
"Hello, {N}!
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IkhlbGxvLCB7Tn0h&input=dGVzdA==)

Comment: Compressing the string will save you 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 21 bytes

```
{print"Hello, "$0"!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uqAoM69EySM1JydfR0FJxUBJUan2//@0/HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 15 bytes

```
s/.*/Hello, &!/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfT0vfIzUnJ19HQU1R////tPx8AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 17 bytes

Trivial and probably as short as it can get.

```
Hello, (?#input)!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/3yM1JydfR0HDXjkzr6C0RFPx//@S8nyuvNRyrpzMvNRiAA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 17 bytes

```javascript
s=>`Hello, ${s}!`
```

Answer (score 0):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 111 bytes

```
3.6009960199602996207252062002020200052062009020200152052062012020200252062044520620325207218215217219620335204
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLDYAwDEPvTMEEyPnQ0iG4MAI3Lq1E91dISRPJzrOsqJlsCSglgYawCyPzznAH/wtMLIHkGAnNwuyrhsvgzHSwV8mP8VTEQzU7374ta8zV7qf2Vj8)

Nothing too special going on here. This is just a glorified cat program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

A lambda, accepting a string and returning a string:

```ruby
->s{"Hello,#{s.size>0?' '+s:s}!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9DoIwFEb3PsWlDgxW4mwCjrj5ALWD0EskaQrpTyICz14bJOB4zznfNb4aQpOHU2FHekOlOnYYbWbbDxbnawrp0V7snNA5cALAKWWwZgkVbEFD53cK8dpMaRD1Q99N9RfsMHZEZPisXyA7mFrde8cA3z3WDuUUXxi0XjnIoeGLFZH1wNfyZ9lW5dtWENQyfAE)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) + `-p`, 16 bytes (not fully compliant)

A full program, which does not support empty inputs (prints nothing) or inputs containing newlines (treats each line as a separate input):

```ruby
$_="Hello, #$_!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyXeVskjNScnX0dBWSVeUen/f/ei1NQ8Bf@ipH/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

The fun trick here: when string interpolation is done on a variable name starting with `$`, the curly braces can be dropped from the normal `#{}` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

```hs
("Hello, "++).(++"!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0PJA8jM11FQ0tbW1NPQ1lZSVNL8n5uYmadgq1BQWhJcUuSTp6CikKagVJ5flJOi9P9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V) / vim, 11 bytes

```
iHello, <esc>A!
```

`<esc>` is a literal escape character

[Try it online! (V)](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9MjNScnX0fBJrU42c5R8f//8vyinJT/umUA)